# Search multiple keywords into multiple rows combining into one

Tags: sql-server

I have a database and structure is like this.
http://prnt.sc/ed3uk5

Id is the primary key of table, Text_Type is Post id(forn key). A long description is splitted into 4 rows and bind with forn key(Type) so basically 4 rows in mentioned screeshot is relates to one post and full description is "KAMPANIEN Ferienwohnung in Villammare  Ferienwohnungen für 6 Personen  geschmackvoller Apartmentkomplex im Cilento Swimming-Pool, Garten, Bar, zum Meer ca. 150 m" when we combine 4 rows. Description on frontend also showing as i showed by combining 4 rows(description is combining by Type).

So now I want to implement search functionality with multiple keywords and description having all keywords will return their "Type". For Example if i search "Personen 150 " then if a post's description having both keywords then it should return thier "Type". if we use `select type from tblName where description like "%Personen %" and description  like "%150 %"` then it will return null because any of row not having both keywords, but i want to search into all rows once by combining into with "Text" so it will return "Text" if both keywords matches in full description(Combining 4 rows by Text), So in this case it should return 1 because full description having both keywords.

Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use aggregation like this:

```
select type
from your_table
group by type
having count(case when description like '%Personen%' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when description like '%150%' then 1 end) > 0;
```

#### How it works:

Using conditional aggregation, we're checking if the given search string is present in any of the descriptions for a given type. The `CASE` will return 1 if the string contained the given search string otherwise it returns null and since we're aggregating, we use `COUNT` to check if one or more descriptions contained the search string.

Comment: Ok let me try Brother

Comment: Might have to drop the first `%` in each of the `LIKE` conditions as it will cause a `FULL TABLE SCAN`, I guess!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer - Then it won't work if the keyword is in between the string

Comment: Working in Mysql, Will work in Sql Server? ,Installing Sql Server and will try.. i will let you know if same will work on sql server.

Comment: Agreed, if and only if the keyword is in between the string!

Comment: Edit question to "n like '%Personen%' then 1 end) > 0 and
 count(case when descr"

Comment: Can you please just elaborate how this query working? i am trying since yesterday and ended up doing post question here

Comment: Thanks, There was a error in query. Please put "and" between two count. http://prntscr.com/ed41ce

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I will study Mysql to improve my skill. Can you please refer some tutorials.

Comment: No it show error "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 ".

Comment: @GurV One more question, can i get type order by relevance. I mean results matching both keywords will appear of top then results matching one keywords will appear next and so on ..?

Comment: @Davinder Yes, you can do that by removing the having clause and getting the counts in the select cause and then sorting by that count - but that will be a new question.

Comment: @GurV Can you please share query because i am not as good in mysql.?

Comment: @Davinder - Please consider accepting this answer and ask a new question

Comment: OK let me post a new question

Comment: @GurV Please post a answer. I really need it.

Comment: @GurV This solution is working in sql server also but i make connectivity with database using "doctrine" and with doctrine, it is not working. Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'texx'