# Search multiple keywords into multiple rows combining into one and then get results by relevance

Tags: sql-server

Moving on with answer "[Search multiple keywords into multiple rows combining into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452572/search-multiple-keywords-into-multiple-rows-combining-into-one#answer-42452604)"

I want to get results with relevance means best matched results will appear first then less matched results like Google does?

Comment: Define *best matched* ....

Comment: Best matched means ,if i searched 3 keywords "a b c" then the results having all keywords will appear first, then results matching two keywords will show and so on...